# CImg transpose function gives wrong width

Tags: c++, cimg

I am using CImg for Image processing assignment. After calling transpose() with the following code

```
cout << image_subsample.width() << ","<<image_subsample.height() << "transpose:" << image_subsample.transpose().width() <<"," <<image_subsample.transpose().height() << endl;
```

The output is

```
1200,1transpose:1200,1200
```

the expected output of transpose is

```
1200,1transpose:1,1200
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually transpose your matrix twice in your example, so the output you get is logical.
Either use get_transpose() or better store your transposed matrix somewhere before displaying its size.

```
CImg<> transp = img.get_transpose();
fprintf(stderr,"%d,%d",transp.width(),transp.height());
```

Comment: Oh got your point. so first call to transpose() would change the object itself and the 2nd call to transpose() is the transpose of transpose. Thanks! got it